# Error while running app android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, every time I try to run my app this error appears:

> Transform output file
>   C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\renderscript\lib\renderscript-v8.jar
>   does not exist.

And the app won't start in the android emulator. I already tried to `clean` my project and `rebuild` it too, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Go to this location  C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\renderscript\lib  and verify if the asked jar exists.

Comment: No, it doesn't even exist the "renderscript" directory

Comment: Don't render the app, put it on an Android device

Comment: Did you work out a fix @AndréSilva?